# State space representation of RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, control-system, passive-networks, state-space

Express the circuit in state space equations, the output is V2. I have tried defining the state variables but got stuck with the differential equations.
[image]

Comment: With homework questions we’re going to need to see what attempts you’ve made and where you’re stuck.

Comment: What @Bryan said- Typically the voltage on the capacitor and current in the inductor are the state variables, so where are you having trouble?

Comment: Homework question?  We are not going to help you solve it until you show the work you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, notice that we can write the output voltage in terms of an inverse Laplace transform:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_2\left(t\right)&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{R}_3\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{R}_3\cdot\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\text{sC}}{\text{sC}}\cdot\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{sC}}{\text{sC}}+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_3\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{\displaystyle\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\\
\\
&=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_3\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{\displaystyle\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_3\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)+\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}\right)^{-1}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_3\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{sC}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)+\text{sL}+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}